# Can you explain this Math.Log10 vs. BigInteger.Log10 behavior?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, biginteger

Can somebody explain the following `System.Numerics.BigInteger` behavior?

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Log10(100));       // prints 2
Console.WriteLine(Math.Log10(1000));      // prints 3 (as expected)

Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Log10(100));  // prints 2
Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Log10(1000)); // prints 3 (as axpected)

var bi100 = new BigInteger(100);
var bi1000 = new BigInteger(1000);

Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Log10(bi100));       // prints 2
Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Log10(bi1000));      // prints 3 (as axpected) 

Console.WriteLine((int)BigInteger.Log10(bi100));  // prints 2
Console.WriteLine((int)BigInteger.Log10(bi1000)); // prints 2 ???????

Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(BigInteger.Log10(bi100)));   // prints 2
Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(BigInteger.Log10(bi1000)));  // prints 2 ???????

Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(BigInteger.Log10(bi100)));  // prints 2
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(BigInteger.Log10(bi1000))); // prints 3 (as expected)
```

**EDIT:** Please note that I know that it's a rouding problem. I want to know **why** the behavior of Math.Log10 and BigInteger.Log10 differs.

Comment: code comment is incorrect for last line: Prints 3 (for me at least)

Answer (score 6):

It is due to precision and rounding.

This line:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)BigInteger.Log10(bi1000));
```

is rounding down the value 2.9999999999999996 to 2, whereas `Console.WriteLine` is writing this out as 3

You can verify this using an intermediate `double` variable, and inspecting its value:

```
double x = BigInteger.Log10(bi1000);
Console.WriteLine((int)x);
```

Comment: -1 Because "3 cannot be represented exactly as binary" is completely false.  All of the operands are exact as well.  But some of the intermediate values may be inexact, depending on how the logarithm function is implemented.

Comment: Cheers Ben. Corrected. I was trying to say what you said more accurately

Comment: This is not a valid answer. It doesn't explain **WHY** the behaviour of Math.Log10 and BigInteger.Log10 differs! Please extend or remove your answer!

Comment: This does explain why.  They are doing the same operation but with different types and therefore with different precision and rounding issues.  You expect both methods to always produce identical results given the same inputs?  If so why have two methods?

Comment: It does indeed explain why this happens. Console.WriteLine rounds up (in this case), (int) truncates down. What more do you need to know?

Answer (score 1):

The big difference is that `BigInteger.Log10(x)` is implemented as `Math.Log(x)/Math.Log(10)`, whereas `Math.Log10(x)` is implemented differently (it's an `extern` so it's not easy to figure out). Regardless, it should be obvious that they use slightly different algorithms for doing a base-10 logarithm, which causes a slight difference in output.

Answer (score -1):

The behaviour differs because they are different types with different representations and different implementations.

Comment: (CW because it's a bad answer to a bad question.)

Comment: No question on rounding issues ever ends happily.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Because it's a rounding issue but the question explicitly excludes that as an answer. It is essentially asking why two different things are different.

Comment: But the difference *is* a rounding issue.

Comment: There are two different pieces of code involved, they propagate rounding errors different. That is one of the differences.

Comment: Actually, probably the more interesting question is why a `Log10` function *specialised* for an integer can't get an exact answer for 1*10^n but the generalised one can...